# On Alarm Clock Plus, what does "Allow auto snooze/dismiss" mean?

Tags: applications, alarm

On the [Alarm Clock Plus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vp.alarmClockPlusDock) app, what does "Allow auto snooze/dismiss" mean? How do I use these features? Can they both be used on one alarm?

Answer (score 1):

**Snooze** - Instead of shutting the alarm off, it would pause it allowing you to sleep for few more minutes. If you see your settings, you could notice the snooze minutes viz - 5, 10, 15 minutes and you can also keep custom minutes. 
When the alarm rings and you feel like having a quick 5 min extended sleep, you hit the snooze option. This comes handy since you dont need to wakeup, set another alarm for next 5-10 minute and doze off.

**Dismiss** - This cancels/shuts the alarm down for that day & time.
You click on the dismiss option when you are ready to ware up!

**Auto Snooze**
That means if there isn't any action (if you don't hit the snooze options) system automatically snooze and again the alarm rings after the x minutes as per the snooze interval. If this auto snooze is not set, you would probably get a notification as "missed alarm". I just updated the answer aswell.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Snooze means delaying the alarm to a certain time. For example, I set an alarm at 7am and the snooze time is 5 minutes. After ringing for some time (dismissed you may call it), it will turn off and snoozes till 7:05am for the next ring.

Dismiss means the alarm is completely turned off. If you do not interact with your phone for a certain while the alarm is on, it will be automatically dismissed (turned off).